# HTML Templating options in C# for generating markup from data

Tags: c#, templates, .net-2.0, webforms

I am currently on the look for Templating library that can generate HTML from Models in C# 2.0( for use with ASP.NET 2.0) since the built in datacontrols do not allow hierarchy more than 3 - 4 levels). I found `Nustache` ( a port of Mustache for use with .NET ) but am at loss when searching for other options available libraries too. Basically this is all i want to do throw a **Model** a tasklist, a todo list etc at the template and the engine renders HTML I just have to stick it up using something like `literalTemplateMarkup.Text = theTemplateMarkup;`

- Some tutorials to get started with the library you suggest would really help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use T4 for this.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, Does `T4 Templates` allow me to do templating as per the requirements? also does it have learning Curve i am really well versed at C# and .NET programming Concepts

Comment: Yes, it's pretty easy to learn.  T4 is what all of the code generation features built into Visual Studio use.